# calling a C# function from a link on an asp page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have an asp login page. When a user clicks a link I need it to call a function in a .cs file to dynamically create the url and redirect. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is it an asp login page or an asp.net login page?

Comment: Then you should remove the "asp.net" tag and just set a "asp" tag instead :)

Comment: hang on, so it's classic ASP?

Comment: my bad, I typed asp but must of auto populated asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dneimke/archive/2004/01/31/65330.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make use of postback. Add for example Button on the page and set property AutoPostBack=true, set it's Click event handler to be a method in your cs file (code behind) and use Response.Redirect() inside that handler